# Динамическая компиляция через CodeDom

Tags: c#, компилятор

Почему [CodeDom Compiler](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom) не может скомпилировать файл в котором присутствует данный символ `$` и подобные `var`?

При компиляции пишет: **Неожиданный символ '$'**

Подскажите может ли **Roslyn** компилировать с данной строкой?
Или же есть какие-нибудь уловки в **CodeDom** для компиляции данного символа?!

Вот класс компилятора:

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace Builder
{
    internal class Compil
    {
        public static bool Compiler(string source, string saveFileName, string outVersion, string resource, string icon = null)
        {
            var compil = new CompilerParameters
            {
                GenerateExecutable = true,
                OutputAssembly = saveFileName
            };

            var options = "/optimize+ /platform:x86 /target:winexe /unsafe";
            if (icon != null)
            {
                options += $" /win32icon:\"{icon}\"";
            }

            compil.CompilerOptions = options;

            compil.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            compil.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
            compil.EmbeddedResources.Add(resource);

            var Results = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {
                    "CompilerVersion", outVersion
                }
            }).CompileAssemblyFromSource(compil, source);

            if (Results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Имеются {Results.Errors.Count} ошибок", "Ошибка компиляции", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                foreach (CompilerError Err in Results.Errors)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(path: "Error_Compiler.txt", contents: $"Ошибка: {Err.ToString()} \r\nСтрока: {Err.Line}\r\n");
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведи пример кода, который не может скомпилировать CodeDom

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31641533/6808809

Comment: Обновил свой вопрос.